# AES encryption and decryption using C++. I get proper output for the encrypted message but the code is not able to decrypt it

Tags: c++, aes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
void InverseMixColumns(unsigned char* state)
{
    unsigned char tmp[16];

    tmp[0] = (unsigned char)mul14[state[0]] ^ mul11[state[1]] ^ mul13[state[2]] ^ mul9[state[3]];
    tmp[1] = (unsigned char)mul9[state[0]] ^ mul14[state[1]] ^ mul11[state[2]] ^ mul13[state[3]];
    tmp[2] = (unsigned char)mul13[state[0]] ^ mul9[state[1]] ^ mul14[state[2]] ^ mul11[state[3]];
    tmp[3] = (unsigned char)mul11[state[0]] ^ mul13[state[1]] ^ mul9[state[2]] ^ mul14[state[3]];

    tmp[4] = (unsigned char)mul14[state[4]] ^ mul11[state[5]] ^ mul13[state[6]] ^ mul9[state[7]];
    tmp[5] = (unsigned char)mul9[state[4]] ^ mul14[state[5]] ^ mul11[state[6]] ^ mul13[state[7]];
    tmp[6] = (unsigned char)mul13[state[4]] ^ mul9[state[5]] ^ mul14[state[6]] ^ mul11[state[7]];
    tmp[7] = (unsigned char)mul11[state[4]] ^ mul13[state[5]] ^ mul9[state[6]] ^ mul14[state[7]];

    tmp[8] = (unsigned char)mul14[state[8]] ^ mul11[state[9]] ^ mul13[state[10]] ^ mul9[state[11]];
    tmp[9] = (unsigned char)mul9[state[8]] ^ mul14[state[9]] ^ mul11[state[10]] ^ mul13[state[11]];
    tmp[10] = (unsigned char)mul13[state[8]] ^ mul9[state[9]] ^ mul14[state[10]] ^ mul11[state[11]];
    tmp[11] = (unsigned char)mul11[state[8]] ^ mul13[state[9]] ^ mul9[state[10]] ^ mul14[state[11]];

    tmp[12] = (unsigned char)mul14[state[12]] ^ mul11[state[13]] ^ mul13[state[14]] ^ mul9[state[15]];
    tmp[13] = (unsigned char)mul9[state[12]] ^ mul14[state[13]] ^ mul11[state[14]] ^ mul13[state[15]];
    tmp[14] = (unsigned char)mul13[state[12]] ^ mul9[state[13]] ^ mul14[state[14]] ^ mul11[state[15]];
    tmp[15] = (unsigned char)mul11[state[12]] ^ mul13[state[13]] ^ mul9[state[14]] ^ mul14[state[15]];

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = tmp[i];
}
void ShiftRows_inverse(unsigned char* state)
{
    unsigned char tmp[16];

    /* Column 1 */
    tmp[0] = state[0];
    tmp[1] = state[13];
    tmp[2] = state[10];
    tmp[3] = state[7];

    /* Column 2 */
    tmp[4] = state[4];
    tmp[5] = state[1];
    tmp[6] = state[14];
    tmp[7] = state[11];

    /* Column 3 */
    tmp[8] = state[8];
    tmp[9] = state[5];
    tmp[10] = state[2];
    tmp[11] = state[15];

    /* Column 4 */
    tmp[12] = state[12];
    tmp[13] = state[9];
    tmp[14] = state[6];
    tmp[15] = state[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        state[i] = tmp[i];
    }
}
void SubBytes_inverse(unsigned char* state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) { // Perform substitution to each of the 16 bytes
        state[i] = inv_s[state[i]];
    }
}
void AddRoundKey(unsigned char* state, unsigned char* roundKey)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] ^= roundKey[i];
}
void Round(unsigned char* state, unsigned char* key)
{
    AddRoundKey(state, key);
    InverseMixColumns(state);
    ShiftRows_inverse(state);
    SubBytes_inverse(state);
}
void InitialRound(unsigned char* state, unsigned char* key)
{
    AddRoundKey(state, key);
    ShiftRows_inverse(state);
    SubBytes_inverse(state);
}
void KeyExpansionCore(unsigned char* in, unsigned char i)
{
    unsigned char t = in[0];
    in[0] = in[1];
    in[1] = in[2];
    in[2] = in[3];
    in[3] = t;

    in[0] = s_box[in[0]];
    in[1] = s_box[in[1]];
    in[2] = s_box[in[2]];
    in[3] = s_box[in[3]];

    in[0] ^= rcon[i];
}
void KeyExpansion(unsigned char* inputKey, unsigned char* expandedKeys)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        expandedKeys[i] = inputKey[i];

    int bytesGenerated = 16;
    int rconIteration = 1;
    unsigned char temp[4];

    while (bytesGenerated < 176) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            temp[i] = expandedKeys[i + bytesGenerated - 4];

        if (bytesGenerated % 16 == 0) {
            KeyExpansionCore(temp, rconIteration++);
        }

        for (unsigned char a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
            expandedKeys[bytesGenerated] = expandedKeys[bytesGenerated - 16] ^ temp[a];
            bytesGenerated++;
        }
    }
}
void SubBytes(unsigned char* state)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = s_box[state[i]];
}
void ShiftRows(unsigned char* state)
{
    unsigned char tmp[16];

    tmp[0] = state[0];
    tmp[1] = state[5];
    tmp[2] = state[10];
    tmp[3] = state[15];

    tmp[4] = state[4];
    tmp[5] = state[9];
    tmp[6] = state[14];
    tmp[7] = state[3];

    tmp[8] = state[8];
    tmp[9] = state[13];
    tmp[10] = state[2];
    tmp[11] = state[7];

    tmp[12] = state[12];
    tmp[13] = state[1];
    tmp[14] = state[6];
    tmp[15] = state[11];

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = tmp[i];
}
void MixColumns(unsigned char* state)
{
    unsigned char tmp[16];
    tmp[0] = (unsigned char)(mul2[state[0]] ^ mul3[state[1]] ^ state[2] ^ state[3]);
    tmp[1] = (unsigned char)(state[0] ^ mul2[state[1]] ^ mul3[state[2]] ^ state[3]);
    tmp[2] = (unsigned char)(state[0] ^ state[1] ^ mul2[state[2]] ^ mul3[state[3]]);
    tmp[3] = (unsigned char)(mul3[state[0]] ^ state[1] ^ state[2] ^ mul2[state[3]]);

    tmp[4] = (unsigned char)(mul2[state[4]] ^ mul3[state[5]] ^ state[6] ^ state[7]);
    tmp[5] = (unsigned char)(state[4] ^ mul2[state[5]] ^ mul3[state[6]] ^ state[7]);
    tmp[6] = (unsigned char)(state[4] ^ state[5] ^ mul2[state[6]] ^ mul3[state[7]]);
    tmp[7] = (unsigned char)(mul3[state[4]] ^ state[5] ^ state[6] ^ mul2[state[7]]);

    tmp[8] = (unsigned char)(mul2[state[8]] ^ mul3[state[9]] ^ state[10] ^ state[11]);
    tmp[9] = (unsigned char)(state[8] ^ mul2[state[9]] ^ mul3[state[10]] ^ state[11]);
    tmp[10] = (unsigned char)(state[8] ^ state[9] ^ mul2[state[10]] ^ mul3[state[11]]);
    tmp[11] = (unsigned char)(mul3[state[8]] ^ state[9] ^ state[10] ^ mul2[state[11]]);

    tmp[12] = (unsigned char)(mul2[state[12]] ^ mul3[state[13]] ^ state[14] ^ state[15]);
    tmp[13] = (unsigned char)(state[12] ^ mul2[state[13]] ^ mul3[state[14]] ^ state[15]);
    tmp[14] = (unsigned char)(state[12] ^ state[13] ^ mul2[state[14]] ^ mul3[state[15]]);
    tmp[15] = (unsigned char)(mul3[state[12]] ^ state[13] ^ state[14] ^ mul2[state[15]]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = tmp[i];
}

void AES_Encrypt(unsigned char* message, unsigned char* key)
{
    unsigned char state[16];
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        state[i] = message[i];

    int numberOfRounds = 9;
    unsigned char expandedKey[176];
    KeyExpansion(key, expandedKey);
    AddRoundKey(state, key);
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRounds; i++) {
        SubBytes(state);
        ShiftRows(state);
        MixColumns(state);
        AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i + 1)));
    }

    SubBytes(state);
    ShiftRows(state);
    AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey + 160);

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        message[i] = state[i];
}
void AESDecrypt(unsigned char* encryptedMessage, unsigned char* expandedKey, unsigned char* decryptedMessage)
{
    unsigned char state[16]; // Stores the first 16 bytes of encrypted message

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        state[i] = encryptedMessage[i];
    }

    InitialRound(state, expandedKey + 160);

    int numberOfRounds = 9;

    for (int i = 8; i >= 0; i--) {
        Round(state, expandedKey + (16 * (i + 1)));
    }

    AddRoundKey(state, expandedKey); // Final round

    // Copy decrypted state to buffer
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        decryptedMessage[i] = state[i];
    }
}
void PrintHex(unsigned char x)
{
    if (x / 16 < 10)
        cout << (char)((x / 16) + '0');
    if (x / 16 >= 10)
        cout << (char)((x / 16 - 10) + 'A');

    if (x % 16 < 10)
        cout << (char)((x % 16) + '0');
    if (x % 16 >= 10)
        cout << (char)((x % 16 - 10) + 'A');
}

int main()
{
    char message[1024];

    cout << "Enter the message to encrypt: ";
    cin.getline(message, sizeof(message));
    cout << message << endl;

    unsigned char key[16] = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
    };

    int originalLen = strlen((const char*)message);
    int lenofPaddedMessage = originalLen;

    if (lenofPaddedMessage % 16 != 0)
        lenofPaddedMessage = (lenofPaddedMessage / 16 + 1) * 16;

    unsigned char* paddedMessage = new unsigned char[lenofPaddedMessage];
    for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i++) {
        if (i >= originalLen)
            paddedMessage[i] = 0;
        else
            paddedMessage[i] = message[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i += 16)
        AES_Encrypt(paddedMessage + i, key);

    cout << " \Encrypted message:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < lenofPaddedMessage; i++) {
        PrintHex(paddedMessage[i]);
        cout << " ";
    }

    delete[] paddedMessage;
    unsigned char expandedKey[176];

    int messageLen = strlen((const char*)paddedMessage);
    unsigned char* decryptedMessage = new unsigned char[messageLen];
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLen; i += 16) {
        AESDecrypt(paddedMessage + i, expandedKey, decryptedMessage + i);
    }
    cout << "Decrypted message in hex:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLen; i++) {
        cout << hex << (int)decryptedMessage[i];
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Decrypted message: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < messageLen; i++) {
        cout << decryptedMessage[i];
        cout << endl;
        delete[] paddedMessage;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code should also contain the s-box,mul3,mul4,mul9,mul12,mul13,mul14 tables but i could not include them as the word limit exceeded. I am getting the encrypted output for the text but not decrypted. it is giving random symbols as the decrypted message instead of the original text back.

https://github.com/nikita890-art/AES-tables/blob/c6fd0e009d90bb4ea3ba8177736965e0a857ea4f/TABLES

Comment: Please provide a [minimal executable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: How do you know it's encrypted properly?

Comment: I won't pretend I grokked all of this, but you don't seem to be providing the key for `AESDecrypt`.

Comment: If your goal is to add encryption and decryption to your application, I suggest you use a well-established, well-vetted, encryption library instead of trying to do this yourself.  If you get anything wrong, that could lead to vulnerabilities in your application.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the expanded keys are provided, which includes the "original" key.

Comment: Can you publish also the sbox and mul arrays together with your code on a git repo ? That would help to repro and read.

Comment: @Soleil: I may be blind, but I don't see where the `expandedKey` variable gets initialized before being passed to `AESDecrypt`. Also `paddedMessage` appears to be deleted before it is passed in.

Comment: The right tool to debug this is your favorite debugger. It also helps to compare encrypted results with a known working encrypt implementation.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError You're right, it is only initialized. The expansion in Encrypt remain local.

Comment: i have added the git hub link for the tables..kindly help me out with the decryption part

Comment: @AdityaKarthik Did you see your expanded key is not actually expanded in decryption ?

Comment: @AdityaKarthik: You have to make the encryption key available to `AESDecrypt` I don't see you doing that in the code above - you just declare `ExpandedKey`. -- Also, why do you `delete[] paddedMessage` before calling `AESDecrypt` with it?

Comment: @Soleil delete[] paddedMessage command was a mistake and i removed it.

Comment: @Soleil how do i solve the issue with the expanded key in the decrypted part.

Comment: Is it possible for you to code it because i am not understanding that part.

Comment: I am getting the error that key is out of scope.

Comment: @AdityaKarthik I have the feeling that you do not understand the most basic concepts of programming; when you do not, search for it, and solve the problem and then the next, until you're done. SO is here when you have a specific problem or eventually a conceptual problem, but no one will explain how to program from scratch to you here. Anyway, a pointer for the scope concept: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/scope-visual-cpp?view=msvc-160

Comment: @Soleil, yes, i am actually learning c++ as i am an electronics student, this is all a little new to me. Anyways, i think i know what mistakes i have made in the code, thx to u guys.